# Ionic/Angular: Can't bind to 'ngForOf', despite correct syntax

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

I am developing an Ionic App with Angular and ran into the following error:

**my.page.ts (Snippet)**

```js
export class MyPage implements OnInit {
  public myArray: Array<string> = [];

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.updateArray();
  }

  updateArray() {
    // Performs API Call and puts the results into 'myArray'
  }
}
```

**my.page.html (Snippet)**

```html
<ion-select interface="popover">
  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of myArray">{{item}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

What I expect is, that the strings contained in the array are mapped to selection options for the 'ion-select'. However, my browser console shows the error `NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-select-option'`

When researching that error, all I can find is the older usage of ngFor (`item of myArray`, etc.) that should no longer be used. However, I already use the up-to-date syntax as far as I understood.

I am running my app using `npx ionic serve --lab`, using Ionic with version 6 and Angular with version 13.

I also tried different components such as 'ion-text', but the same error occurs.

Also, I verified that the data from the API-Call is stored correctly in the array by printing it after the http-request has finished.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Here is my my.app.module-file:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { MyPageRoutingModule } from './my-routing.module';

import { MyPage } from './my.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    MyPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [MyPage]
})
export class MyPageModule {}
```

Comment: Have you imported the Angular's `CommonModule` into the module that has `MyPage` declared?

Comment: @Joulukuusi Yes, it is imported in my.module.ts. I also tried to import it in app.module.ts as well, but that makes no difference

Comment: Could you add your module declaration to the original question please? That might shed some more light.

Comment: @BenBrookes I've just appended it to the question

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error and added a stackblitz to the answer. The error solves with assigning a value.

Answer (score 2):

This error of type `Can't bind to 'something' since it isn't a known property of 'element'` may occur when you are using an attribute that not exist in the target element or like in this case, because you are trying to use an attribute directive that can't be found.
In this case you are trying to use `ngForOf` directive but it can't be found, so you have to ensure that you are importing the host module for that directive in the host module of your component. To solve this case you have to import `CommonModule` in the module where you declare `MyPage` like this.

```
  import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

  @NgModule({
      declarations: [MyPage, ...],
      imports: [CommonModule, ...]
  })
```

**EDIT**

Is important to assign a `value` for `<ion-select-option>` because the default is `undefined`.
I was able to reproduce your problem on a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-ga6yey?file=src/app/my/my.component.html) and got the same error when not assign a `value`.

Comment: I've just appended the module file to the original question. It seems to contain everything you mentioned. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Did you re-run the `ng serve` after applying the fix?

Comment: Yes, several times. The common module was imported by default, however. Also, control-clicking on `*ngFor`in the HTML forwards me to the 'common.d.ts' file from Angular, so at least VS Code seems to understand everything as supposed.

Comment: Really weird. In order to work around this and discard some conflict with ion-select-option have you tried to wrap the ion-select-option inside ng-container.
`<ng-container *ngFor="let item of myArray">
  <ion-select-option>{{item}}</ion-select-option>
</ng-container>`

Comment: Also set a `value` attribute to ion-select-option. The default value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call ngIf to make sure the data isn't being loaded BEFORE your myArray data is ready.

Change your HTML code to below to check if there is any data exists in your array, if not, it will remain hidden and inactive until there is a data.

```
<ion-select *ngIf="myArray.length > 0" interface="popover">
     <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of myArray">{{item}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to give a short update!

Eventually, the issue was not really Angular/Ionic-related. Instead, the issue was that the function I wrote to update the array was a traditional one instead of an arrow function.

Due to that, 'this' belonged to a different context, so by overriding the array on which the UI is bound, actually a new variable was created.

The UI therefore wasn't affected by the change. Changing the function to an arrow function solved the problem.